# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have new to PHP programming and looking to create access a database I created. I have been able to get a successful connection going between PHP and my database, but the problem arises when I try to run a simple query.

I get the dreaded message `mysqli_query()` expects parameter 1 to be mysqli. I have seen numerous issues on this throughout the internet. I still am unable to resolve my situation. Can someone please address my code here:

```
$mysqli= mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password,'japanesewords')
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
 mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM japanesedefinition') or die(mysql_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: Your mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` **typo?**

Comment: No, I am unsure where the typo is. I really am new at this. Can you please explain a bit more for me. I really want to understand this.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean, I think I fixed it, but now I get another error message: Access denied for user.

Comment: @user1459917 Check all your credentials then, connection-username-password-database.

Comment: @user1459917 Try using `$mysqli= mysqli_connect("$hostname","$username","$password","japanesewords")` with double quotes, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone [**as per my comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648078/mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli#comment27458536_18648078) I asked the OP to check out all info.

Comment: THank you all for you help. I am so stuck. I was able to connect before just not do a query, now it appears that I don't have permission to access my own database.

Comment: I went through all of this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html

Comment: @user1459917 Do you have access to Cpanel and/or PHPAdmin?

Comment: @Panique Opps shame on me, thank you for your comment it was very constructive.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for help. I did create a user that has all privileges was able to connect ('I think'). This sad thing is that after I connect I am unable to find my database even though I am clearly typing in "show databases;" and I see it as clear as day, but the PHP code does not see it.   mysqli_select_db($test,'japanesewords');  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `PDO`?

```
<?php

try {

    // config
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=japanesewords;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $options = array(
        // necessary for rowCount() on SELECT
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
        // for catching SQL errors as PDOException
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        // default fetch mode is used for iterating PDOStatement by foreach() 
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
    );

    // connect
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    // execute SQL
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM japanesedefinition');

    // check row count
    if (!$stmt->rowCount()) {
        throw new Exception('no data');
    }

    // fetch results and display
    echo "<p>\n";
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        printf("foo: %s; bar: %s;<br />\n", $row->foo, $row->bar);
    }
    echo "</p>\n";

} catch (Exception $e) {

    printf("<p>%s</p>\n", $e->getMessage());

}
```

I don't know whether you're japanese or not, remark the summary in Japanese for connectiong to MySQL with PHP.
http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/b00b72c5c95aac573b71